# how to use a service inside another service in symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have a service setup in symfony 2.6 by name `ge_lib` and it looks like below

```
    ge_lib:
    class: GE\RestBundle\Services\GELib
    arguments: [@session, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @manage_ge_proc]
```

inside GELib.php I have a requirement to use a function from another service `manage_ge_proc`

```
    manage_ge_proc:
    class: GE\RestBundle\Services\GEManageProcedure
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @manage_ge_native_query]
```

if I try to use it this way, it is not working

```
$emailInv = $this->get('manage_ge_proc');
$sendStatus = $emailInv->pSendGeneralEmail(.....);
```

It gives error saying that unable to find any get function by that name. generally this -> `$this->get('manage_ge_proc');`works in any controller.But how do i use it in service?.

I tried `$this->getContainer()->get('manage_ge_proc');` but it did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This call is fetching service from  DI container, which you dont have in your service

```
$this->get('manage_ge_proc');
```

It works in controller because DI container is automatically injected there.

Since you have this line in you `services.yml`, which tells Symfony to inject `@manage_de_proc` service into `ge_lib` constructor

```
arguments: [@session, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @manage_ge_proc]
```

you should be able to pick `@manage_ge_proc` from constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(
    Session $session,
    EntityManager $entityManager, 
    GEManageProcedure $manageGeProc
)
{
    //... whatever you do in your constructor
    $this->manageGeProc = $manageGeProc;
}
```

Comment: this is the way to do it, make sure that the service you need is injected into your other one. You COULD if you wanted to inject the container and user the container trait in order to use $this->container->get(""); but that wouldnt be the best solution here.

Comment: @svgrafov should the constructor  look like this - `public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $emr)` instead of just variable names as arguments?. If yes, then should I add class name of the service `GEManageProcedure` as argument?. like `public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $emr, GEManageProcedure $manageDeProc)`

Comment: Yeah, it is possible and even highly encouraged.